# Проверка всех input с checked внутри блока

Tags: javascript

Есть блок внутри которого находятся radio input. Может быть так, что инпут будет выбран при загрузке страницы, а может быть не выбран. Как проверить, если хоть один инпут выбран внутри блока? Пример для тестов:

```js
let select = document.querySelector('.block'),
  radioItem = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');
radioItem.forEach(item => {
  if (item.value == 'val1') {
    item.checked = true;
  } else {
    item.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="field">
    <label><input type="radio" class="radio" name="1" value="val1"><span class="val">Val1</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label><input type="radio" class="radio" name="2" value="val2" checked><span class="val">Va2</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть, если у второго инпута есть `checked`, то не запускать условие, если ни один инпут внутри блока не имеет `checked` - запустить.

Comment: а почему бы не использовать [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: так же добавьте информации в вопрос о том когда должна выполняться  проверка условия